# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicity

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the last line of a file. And then grab the first two digits in the file and add one to them so I can write that to a file with a new product.

```
with io.open('/home/jake/Projects/Stock','r+', encoding='utf8' as f:
    for line in f:
        if NewProduct == line[3:]:
             print ("You already sell this product, if you wish to add more stock please return to the menu")
        else:
             ProductPrice = input("Input A Price For This Product >> ")
             ProductAmount = input("How Many Do We Have In Stock >> ")
             last_line = f.readlines()
             New = last_line[-1]+int(1)
             Together = (New, NewProduct)
             TogetherV2 = (New, ProductPrice)
             TogetherV3 = (New, ProductAmount)
```

The file I'm reading and appending to is in this format

```
01 Tomatos
02 Chocolate
```

etc... I know I haven't added the part to grab the first two numbers from the file yet, I'm currently trying to grab the whole line and then adapt it to the first two numbers but haven't managed to. I know this is a possible duplicate I just couldn't understand or make a solution to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What line is the error pointing to?

Comment: If you are just seeking for a way to convert string to int, explicitly convert it (e.g. int('12')). Vice versa.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `New = last_line[-1]+int(1)`? This produce the problem.

Comment: File "/home/jake/Test.py", line 139, in AddProducts
 new = last_line[-1]+int(1)

Comment: What does the last line look like? It appears as though you are trying to concatenate a string to an integer and I don't believe that will work.

Comment: I'm trying to grab the last line, once I've grabbed that I haven't added this part yet as I do not know how, but I want to select the 02 and then add 1 to it so that I can use it as an id for the new product I'm going to add

Comment: Last line would look like '03 Apples' and normally I'd select a normal line like line[0:1] for the first 2 characters but when I do it with the last line I'm unable to do that

Comment: `int(last_line[-1][:1]) + 1`?

Comment: @DavidZemens Edit, my mistake. It works I think. Checking now

Comment: I revised my comment can you try again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of your `last_line` is a string, like `"03 Apples"`. You're trying to add the integer `1` to that string, which raises the conversion error.

To slice the value portion, and explicitly convert it to `int` type (which will allow you to add with other integer, do this:

```
New = int(last_line[-1][:1]) + 1
```